Creating a pylint coverage report
We have a lot of legacy python code in our github repo that has the very useful type and pylint checks disabled:
# type: ignore
# pylint: skip-file

In some files where this is not the case, there are whole sections with no pylint coverage.
We'd like to create a pylint coverage report, which is similar to the pytest coverage report, and shows which files are covered and how much is covered.
Are there any tools that do this automatically?

I'm not aware of any.  You could write a regex that scans for # pylint or # type: ignore text.

That is a good question. No solution that I know of. -- Something you could try, though... -- When a file is skipped with skip-file, pylint sends the file-ignored message, this message is disabled by default but it can be enabled explicitly, though. So you could try to run something like pylint --enable file-ignored .... That is of course still very far from what you are asking for. Maybe there are more options that can help get closer to the goal. -- For sure I would be interested as well.

You can activate file-ignored and  locally-disabled. You can then use the results if it's not exactly what you wanted (there's a json reporter if you need to modify it programmatically).
